# How to consolidate data within multiple cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel

How to consolidate data within two or more cells without merging? Does anybody have a solution or idea for that:

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with a so-called **pivot table**:

[image]

There are lots of instructions out there on how to create a pivot table (this depends on your version of Excel), but you need to change at least these options:

- Use Length and Width as 'Row fields'
- You want the pivot table to be displayed in 'Tabular form'
- You probably want to hide the +/- buttons which are shown by default.

Comment: I use Excel 2016. I do not understand how to set the pivot table for the result as from the picture?

Comment: Windows or Mac? First, select your source table; there should be an option Insert Pivot Table in the menu; in the field list, select the fields you want to use. I can't post a step by step solution now, I'm on mobile.